# Validate login page in Twitter in iPhone

Tags: iphone, twitter, authentication, validation

I am woking on twitter application. I have used "Twitter Request" package and implemented in my application and posted a tweet messages successfully. Now i want to validate the login page, whether the user typed the user name and pass word is correct or not. If the user types the correct datails, the message will be posted otherwise display some alert message. And i have one doubt, which API is used to better in the appln?(MGTwitterEngine,Oauth etc.,). I am very new to this topics. So please guide me. Is there any sample code or tutorials are availble for validation?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter Request Package is not enough to implement TWitter (to validate) login authentication and for implement that before you should be known about OAuth or XAuth process. I successfully implement that with XAuth authentication after period of long time. If you follow the link then you can do twitter validation as you expect.[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244865/is-there-any-demo-app-available-for-iphonemgtwitterengine-for-twitter-integratio/3337346#3337346)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the link.

http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2010/03/using-xauth-an-alternate-oauth-from-twitter/

http://aralbalkan.com/3133

I hope definitely it will help you.

Comment: @MS Nathan. Thanks for Reply. Its really useful.