# Tutorial for MGTwitterEngine for Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, twitter

Is there a good tutorial available to use MGTwitterEngine on the Iphone?
Call me dumb but I cant figure it out.
All I want to do is update the users twitter status through my Iphone app.
Basic Authentication is not supported any more. So how do i do this? Im looking for the easiest most simple way available.

Comment: check this answer out to a question very similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244865/is-there-any-demo-app-available-for-iphonemgtwitterengine-for-twitter-integration

Answer (score 4):

try this:

http://icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/

Comment: I have problem in fetching user timeline and i am already done tweet using your link but i can not fetch timeline so can you help me??