# Twitter login screen with MGTwitterEngine

Tags: iphone, twitter, mgtwitterengine

How can i use own customize page for login to twitter rather than web view present in MGTwitterEngine.

I am using MGTwitter engine for this.login procees with their web view runs smoothly.

Comment: if you are trying to modify the Login screen for twitter, then you can't do this using oauth.

Comment: Did you customize login page?

Comment: @llya Blokh, No i didn't customize the login page, but add a tool bar with cancel button in that page.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244865/is-there-any-demo-app-available-for-iphonemgtwitterengine-for-twitter-integratio) for answer