# What is the best way to integrate Twitter into an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, twitter

I didn't think i would ask such a question but i simply have no choice. Before asking it i've been googling and searching and trying to implement twitter with `MGTwitterEngine` and i have already wasted a huge amount of time, so i need an advice from people who have already dealt with Twitter in iOS apps. I believe this is an appropriate question for SO.

Ok, all i need is to provide user with ability to simply tweet from inside my app. It looked really easy, but in reality:

1) The Social Framework provided by Apple doesn't suit me because before posting to Twitter user has to be already signed into their Twitter account in Settings.

2)Using `MGTwitterEngine` and `SA_OauthTwitterEngine` is so incredibly difficult! I've wasted the whole day to implement authorization and tweets and this is not what i need cause this functionality works on one single device (on other devices i'm not able to authorize the app) and even on this device it works just awfully. If i don't get an appropriate answer to this question i will probably be forced to waste a whole week to make it work (or not work), i have no other choice.

So my question is - isn't there any other simple way to integrate Twitter into an iOS app? How did you do that?

Comment: which version of os do you support?

Comment: DETwitter is working fine.

Comment: @ArpitParekh what is that? i can't find it google. can you give me a link?

Comment: then use inbuilt twitter framework http://www.raywenderlich.com/5519/beginning-twitter-in-ios-5

Comment: @Andrey Chernukha u got the solution ? solution is available please share me

Answer (score 2):

iOS 5 is having built in support for twitter framework.

Follow this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5519/beginning-twitter-in-ios-5). It explains twitter integration in a great manner.

Comment: sorry I typed the answer as your answer was being updated. apologies

Comment: @PrajwalUdupa No worries..Enjoy..!!

Comment: No, this is not what i need. The user has to be already signed in into  their Twitter account in Settings to be able to post, when i need the user to login right through the application

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244865/is-there-any-demo-app-available-for-iphonemgtwitterengine-for-twitter-integrati

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios) is the best way to integrate twitter in iOS Apps.

You can integrate twitter on the fly with the help of [Fabric](https://dev.twitter.com/fabric/overview).

Comment: @JAGAT can you, instead of applying the boilerplate "must be in proper format", mention in the edit message _what you changed_? Thanks.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you for your suggestion. I agree with you. Next time i will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Then there is a built in framework to integrate twitter [see this.](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios) and aslo use DETwitter engine if you support ios 4 also.

Comment: you dont need to worry about oAuth at all.

Comment: Can you give me a link for DETwitter? I can't find it in google.